# Can't access Web Api over https from Web Client on the same server

Tags: ssl, asp.net-web-api, https

I have a Web Client and a Web Api running on the same server which are both set up as separate applications under the common IIS default website. The website is configured with two https bindings, one for each app. The Web Client talks to the Api.

Now to my problem. I can't get https to work. When I specify that the Web Client should access the Web Api over https I get get an error while accessing the Web Api from my machine over https works fine.

Web Client (app server) -> Web Api (app server)

- ok:     http://"server name"/webapi/
- not ok: https://"server name"/webapi/
- not ok: http://"host name"/webapi/
- not ok: https://"host name"/webapi/

Web Client (my machine) -> Web Api (app server)

- ok: http://"server name"/webapi/
- not ok: https://"server name"/webapi/
- ok: http://"host name"/webapi/
- ok: https://"host name"/webapi/

Also, both sites are configured to use windows authentication.

Answer (score 1):

The problem seems to have been that I was using an alias as "host name" which for some reason won't work in this scenario. Calling the Web API using alias from another machine works fine but not between the Web client and Web API on the same server. Changing "host name" to full computer name together with creating a matching certificate solved it.

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem might be with the Double-Hop Authentication issue. Refer to these links for information and a potential solution:

[ASP.NET Web Blog about the issue](https://weblogs.asp.net/owscott/iis-windows-authentication-and-the-double-hop-issue)

[Steps to get around the issue](https://forums.asp.net/t/1799477.aspx?How%20do%20I%20achieve%20double%20hop%20authentication)

Without an actual error code (502, 403, etc.) it's hard to determine what the actual issue might be. One other thing might be if you are using a self-signed SSL cert you may have to manually allow the application to connect to the website with an invalid/self-signed cert, as you indicated it works without HTTPS (or so I read it as).

Comment: Looks like i'm getting a 401 Unauthorized. The certificates are not self-signed.

Comment: Ah, I hit this exact same issue then. You need to go into regedit and manually add a new value to allow connections back to the same server. Follow the steps [here](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/scottstewart/2014/09/15/disableloopbackcheck-when-routing-through-a-load-balancer-powershell-sample-included/) to get around this issue.

Comment: Well i'm not using a load balancer so I don't know if this fix apply.